# Issue with adding a device to the provisioning profile using apple store connect api

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

Trying to connect with the api,*[https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/profiles/{profile_id}](https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/profiles/%7Bprofile_id%7D)* with method as patch and request body as { 'data': { 'relationships': { 'devices': { 'data': [ { 'type': 'devices', 'id':device_id } ] } } } }

```
import json
import requests


def add_device_to_provisioning_profile(profile_id,device_id,auth_token):
    url = f"https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/profiles/{profile_id}"
    request_body = {
        'data': {
            'relationships': {
                'devices': {
                    'data': [
                        {
                            'type': 'devices',
                            'id': device_id
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    x = requests.patch(
        url,
        headers={
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {auth_token}",
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data=json.dumps(request_body)
    )

    return x.text
```

It shows 403 error and couldn't find the issue with it.The api key and the auth key file used for generating the jwt token is provided with admin access to all.Through this api we can fetch the details but can't add the device to the provisioning profile.Please suggest a solution to resolve the issue.

```
 {
  "errors" : [ {
    "id" : "fe4d9ab1-72a0-4fe9-a3c3-6c8c5fb2316a",
    "status" : "403",
    "code" : "FORBIDDEN_ERROR",
    "title" : "This request is forbidden for security reasons",
    "detail" : "The API key in use does not allow this request"
  } ]
}
```